# Problems with Html.DropDownList in ASP.NET RC1

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For some reason my drop down list is not retaining it's selected value - I know I am missing something simple here. Thanks for any comments!

Controllers

```
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        ViewData["MonitoringType"] = new SelectList(myModel.GetMonitoringType(), "Category", "Category");
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Test(FormCollection formValues)
    {
        ViewData["MonitoringType"] = new SelectList(myModel.GetMonitoringType(), "Category", "Category", formValues["MonitoringType"]);
        return View();
    }
```

And View:

This doesn't work

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("MonitoringType", (SelectList)ViewData["MonitoringType"],new {style = "width: 300px;"})%>
```

This works

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("MonitoringType")%>
```

Answer (score 2):

quote from controller:

```
    var projects = from project in DB.Projects
                   orderby project.Name
                   select new { project.Id, project.FullName };
    ViewData["ProjectId"] = new SelectList(projects, "Id", "FullName", selectedProjectId);
```

quote from page:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("ProjectId", "-- All Projects --")%>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I guess I should have made it a bit more explicit "Category" is distinct and is both the value and the text. And really where it is failing is the (SelectList)ViewData["MonitoringType"]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer to a similar question. It appears there is a bug in the DropDownList extension method when using methods other than DropDownList(name).

[Html.DropDownList in ASP.NET MVC RC (refresh) not pre-selecting item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589935/html-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc-rc-refresh-not-pre-selecting-item)