# Set dropdownlist selected value in a table based on another cell (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I want to create an 'editable' table in MVC, where each row will have its own dropdownlist to update the row value. How do I set the dropdownlist selected value on page load for rows that were already updated before.

My current Razor code is like this:

```
<tbody>
   @foreach (var conversion in Model.PaginatedConversions)
   {
        <tr>
             <td>@conversion.tSystem.systemName</td>
             <td>@conversion.conversionStandardValue</td>
             <td>@Html.DropDownList("ConversionStandardIdFor" + conversion.conversionID.ToString(), Model.AvailableValuesForConversion, "")</td>
             <td>@conversion.conversionDescription</td>
             <td>@conversion.conversionDateInput</td>
             <td>@conversion.ConversionDateConverted</td>
             <td>@conversion.ConversionUser</td>
        </tr>
   }
```

But I cannot set the selected value of each dropdown. How can I do this? Thanks for the help!

**Edit1** : This code loops a model property (`Model.PaginatedConversions`), which is of type `List<Conversion>`. The Conversion class is as followed:

```
public class Conversion {
    int ConversionId { get;set; }
    string ConversionValue { get; set; }
    int ConversionConvertedValue { get; set; }
}
```

The goal of the table is to create editable rows for user to map the `ConversionValue` to another value that can be selected in `Model.AvailableConversionValues`. This converted value will be stored in `ConversionConvertedValue`.

The property `Model.AvailableConversionValues` are of type `List<SelectListItem>` that contains the available values user can choose from to map the ConversionValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the ConversionValue as a name didn't work. I created another method in the ViewModel, and use that instead for getting the SelectListItem, passing the selected value to be selected in the ListItem.

```
<td>@Html.DropDownList("ConversionFor" + conversion.conversionID.ToString(), Model.GetAvailableConversionValues(conversion.conversionStandardID))</td>
```

And in the ViewModel I have this method:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetAvailableConversionValues(int? selectedValue)
    {
        if (selectedValue != null)
        {
            SelectListItem selectItem = AvailableValuesForConversion.Where(t => int.Parse(t.Value) == selectedValue).SingleOrDefault();

            if (selectItem != null)
            {
                selectItem.Selected = true;
            }
        }
        return AvailableValuesForConversion;
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DropDownListFor` html helper by passing the option's value that has to be selected as the first parameter and the collection as the second.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.LastSelected, Model.AvailableValuesForConversion, "")
```

[DropDownList setting selected item in asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410543/dropdownlist-setting-selected-item-in-asp-net-mvc)

[razor Html.DropdownList provide "Please select" as optionLabel AND "US" as selectedValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036457/razor-html-dropdownlist-provide-please-select-as-optionlabel-and-us-as-selec)

**UPDATE:**

There may be a good solution but this is what I come up.

The thing is the `DropDownList` method searches the selected value based on the passed `name` in the `Model`, `ViewData` etc. So the idea is add a property in the `ViewData` with the dropdown's name and set the value to the one that you need to set in the dropdown and you are done!

I thing you have to set the `ConversionValue` to the dropdown else update the code accordingly.

```
   @foreach (var conversion in Model.PaginatedConversions)
   {
        var ddId = "ConversionStandardIdFor" + conversion.conversionID.ToString();

        ViewData[ddId] = conversion.ConversionValue;

        <tr>
             <td>@conversion.tSystem.systemName</td>
             <td>@conversion.conversionStandardValue</td>
             <td>@Html.DropDownList(ddId, Model.AvailableValuesForConversion, "")</td>
             <td>@conversion.conversionDescription</td>
             <td>@conversion.conversionDateInput</td>
             <td>@conversion.ConversionDateConverted</td>
             <td>@conversion.ConversionUser</td>
        </tr>
   }
```

Comment: The problem with using DropDownListFor, is that I'm not taking the selected value from the model. But from a property of the Model, that I'm looping to create the table rows (Model.PaginatedConversions)

Comment: Can you post this class Model.AvailableValuesForConversion?